# Invalid cell coordinate error phpExcel -?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I worked on retrieving excel data, but I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Invalid cell coordinate B in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\excelUpLoad\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:594
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\excelUpLoad\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(1218):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('B') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\excelUpLoad\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(1178):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->createNewCell('B') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\excelUpLoad\main.php(43):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('B', 2) #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\excelUpLoad\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line
>   594

This is my code:

```
  try
    {
        // 업로드 된 엑셀 형식에 맞는 Reader객체를 만든다.
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filename);
        // 읽기전용으로 설정
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        // 엑셀파일을 읽는다.
        $objExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
        // 첫번째 시트를 선택
        $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $objWorksheet = $objExcel->getActiveSheet();
}catch(exception $e)
{
  echo "엑셀파일을 읽는 도중 오류가 발생하였습니다.";
}

echo "<table>";

// print_r ($objWorksheet); //엑셀 파일 읽어 왔는지 확인

$maxRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();

for($i=2; $i<=$maxRow; $i++)
{
  //두번째 행부터 읽어 온다 왜냐하면 첫번째 행은 subject이니깐~~
  echo "<tr>";
  $area = $objWorksheet->getCell('B', $i)->getValue(); //1번째 열
  $area2 = $objWorksheet->getCell('C', $i)->getValue(); //2번째 열
  $mediaName = $objWorksheet->getCell('D', $i)->getValue(); //3번째 열
  $discount = $objWorksheet->getCell('E', $i)->getValue(); //4번째 열
  $locationName = $objWorksheet->getCell('F', $i)->getValue(); //5번째 열
  $displayContent = $objWorksheet->getCell('G', $i)->getValue(); //6번째 열
  $manager = $objWorksheet->getCell('H', $i)->getValue(); //7번째 열
  $FieldContent = $objWorksheet->getCell('I', $i)->getValue(); //8번째 열
  $changeContent = $objWorksheet->getCell('J', $i)->getValue(); //9번째 열
  $blank = $objWorksheet->getCell('K', $i)->getValue(); //10번째 열
  $permissionDate = $objWorksheet->getCell('L', $i)->getValue(); //11번째 열
  $permissionCode = $objWorksheet->getCell('M', $i)->getValue(); //12번째 열
  $code = $objWorksheet->getCell('N', $i)->getValue(); //13번째 열
  $editor = $objWorksheet->getCell('O', $i)->getValue(); //14번째 열
  $lat = $objWorksheet->getCell('P', $i)->getValue(); //15번째 열
  $lng = $objWorksheet->getCell('Q', $i)->getValue(); //16번째 열
  echo"<td>".$area."</td>";
  echo $area;
  echo"<td>".$area2."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$mediaName."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$discount."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$locationName."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$displayContent."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$manager."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$FieldContent."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$changeContent."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$blank."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$permissionDate."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$permissionCode."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$code."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$editor."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$lat."</td>";
  echo"<td>".$lng."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel: Invalid cell coordinate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147526/phpexcel-invalid-cell-coordinate-error)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please understand: the primary language here is English. Keeping your native language comments in your source code doesn't help the majority of readers here. It rather confuses them. It would also be really helpful if you would clearly mark the line that gives that is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: I forgot to change the notes into English. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell coordinate is first parameter from getCell method.
https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_getCell